# Why was the question about All Halo Books List (100702) closed again, after it was re-opened?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

Ok, so the question, [Is there a list of all Halo-related reading?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100702/all-halo-books-list), was closed and then re-opened, after a bit of discussions in the comments section.

The question was then re-closed very soon after. See the [revision history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/100702/revisions).

And the Off-topic reason being:

> "Requests for lists of works or recommendations are off-topic as they do not fit our questions and answers format. Feel free to ask about people's favorites in chat."

**Why was this question closed?**

What makes it "off-topic"? It's definitely not asking for a recommendation. It's asking for all the relevant source material for that certain canon.

It's:

- Answerable
- Definite list
- On-topic (Halo is very Sci-Fi)
- Not asking for our 'favourites', etc

Related (on-topic) questions:

- [Where does the background story in A Song of Ice and Fire come from?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56992/where-does-the-background-story-in-a-song-of-ice-and-fire-come-from)
- [How many Marvel Earths (Universes) are there?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89740/how-many-marvel-earths-universes-are-there)
- [What should I do if I want to cover 100% of Star Wars EU but don't want to play the games?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/41192/what-should-i-do-if-i-want-to-cover-100-of-star-wars-eu-but-dont-want-to-play)
- [Is there an "official"-ish complete chronological order for Star Wars C-canon material (books+comics+games)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2289/is-there-an-official-ish-complete-chronological-order-for-star-wars-c-canon-ma)

---

<sup>I am most definitely not asking for people to justify themselves having gone against what I've said. I just want to get a consensus on whether or not this is on/off-topic and **why**.</sup>

Comment: https://www.halowaypoint.com/en-us/forums/db05ce78845f4120b062c50816008e5d/topics/halo-canon-order-halo-3-and-before/23bec818-d9c5-4932-981b-61efe8532f61/posts - Insanely long answer anyone? Ooh, yes please.

Comment: If the close reason was that the answer is too long, then the "too-broad" option should have been used no?

Comment: I didn't close it. I was merely commenting that it's **not** readily answerable. That was your point #1

Comment: @Richard **1/2** I know you didn't. And again, this isn't to call out those who did. People's votes go where they will. Just want to understand. So, if it's not **readily** answerable, it's off topic? As in, do we concentrate on low hanging fruit? I agree that it does seem like it's a huge piece of canon, with lots of media, but surely the list is finite, and the info has to be *somewhere*, no?

Comment: @Richard **2/2** Additionally, just so I get it, are we closing this because it's essentially asking "give me all the things from this canon"? Or that it just so happens that it's a huuuuge piece of work and too much for our site's format?

Comment: The close reason explicitly states that answers require an extensively long answer are not a good fit for the site. For example, "*what is the chronology of all Star Trek comics?*"